# Build de módulos javascript, como empacotar arquivos (modules)?

Tags: javascript, json, grunt, requirejs

Estou a usar o **require js** e quero otimizar as requisições, lendo um pouco da [documentação no github](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js), sei que é possível configurar uma task no **Grunt** para concatenação de meus módulos mais estou um pouco confuso em como configurar essa task e como exatamente vai funcionar. Estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você já testou o [grunt-contrib-requirejs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs)?

Comment: Leia essa [discussão](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/192) sobre o uso do grunt-usemin.

Answer (score 1):

O que você está procurando irá achar nos artigos abaixo, exemplos de como proceder com o uso do RequireJS e a concatenação/minificação do mesmo:

- [Optimize (Concatenate and Minify) RequireJS Projects](http://www.webdeveasy.com/optimize-requirejs-projects/)
- [Run RequireJs With GruntJs](http://jaketrent.com/post/run-requirejs-with-gruntjs).

Observe o uso do uglify para optimização.